# Почему не выводит функции в окно приложения Ткинтера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, requests, bs4

Решил зделать приложение на ткинтере ошибка немогу вывести в окно приложение спарсенные данные.Как это зделать?

```
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

import requests
import txt as txt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import string
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from itertools import groupby
window = Tk()

try:
    def seasonvar_new():
        url = "http://seasonvar.ru/"
        root = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(root.content, "lxml")
        g = soup.find("div", {"class": "news"})
        for link12 in g.findAll('div'):  # собирает текст сериалов
            href3 = link12.getText().split()
            line1 = [i for i in [href3.strip() for href3 in href3] if i]# [0]= только название



            # for link1 in g.findAll('a'):
    # href = link1.get('href')
    # print(href)

    def animedia():
        ser = requests.get("https://amedia.online/")
        soup =BeautifulSoup(ser.text, "lxml")
        content = soup.find("div", {"class": "section-content clearfix"})
        for link1 in content.findAll('div'):
            href21 = link1.get_text('a').split('a')
            x = href21
            new_x = [el for el, _ in groupby(x)]
            x = new_x[0].split()

            #contentw = content.find_all("div", {"class": "newtitle"}).get_text(separator=u"<div>")


    def tkinter():
        window = Tk()
        window.geometry('1200x720')        
        window.title("ModBusReader")
        #button
        b1 = Button(text="Сериалы", width=10, height=4, command=seasonvar_new)
        b1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        b1.pack()

        #многострочное поле
        fild = Text()
        txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=40, height=10)
        txt.grid(column=4, row=2)
        txt.insert(INSERT, seasonvar_new)
        fild.pack()
         b1 = Button(text="Сериалы", width=10, height=4, command=animedia())
        b1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        b1.pack()

        #многострочное поле
        fild = Text()
        txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=40, height=10)
        txt.grid(column=4, row=2)
        txt.insert(INSERT, animedia())
        fild.pack()
        window.mainloop()

    tkinter()



except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

П.С Как убрать дубликаты это нетекст в первой функции а названия ссылки.А вовторой появляетца отступы?
П.С Я уже и лейбел и энтри , все что можно вставлял даже пробывал многострочное текст выводить просмотрел курс делал по курсу но непонимаю как вывести данные две функции.Я новичек только начал изучать ткинтер смотрел даже код других непонимаю как так я вставляю лейбел мне в консоль выводит а не в окно приложения.Если нетрудно коротко  что отвечает за вывод информации в окно приложения?
Я уже три дня одну справку пересматриваю и непонимаю вообще нечего что-куда.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь показать ошибку? Если у тебя ошибка "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?", то попробуй установить lxml через pip:

`pip install lxml` или `pip3 install lxml`

Comment: импортнул давно а пишет одно и тоже вот это..."cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack"

Comment: /а еще вот это пишет <function seasonvar_new at 0x0000017EA7602D90>

Comment: пишет "<function seasonvar_new at 0x0000017EA7602D90>" потому что функция seasonvar_new не вызывается (для вызова надо поставить круглые скобки в конце): `txt.insert(INSERT, seasonvar_new())` + обе функции ничего не возвращают

Comment: Ок, посмотрел подправил заработало, а как вставить картинку относительный путь?У меня проблема с относительным путем.